# Expression mysql NOW() in Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

How to use the expression mysql NOW() in doctrine querybuilder?

Answer (score 53):

In Doctrine2 you have to use one of the following instead of `NOW()`.
This:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Or:

```
...
createQuery(...'WHERE x.date = :now')
->setParameter('now', new \DateTime('now'))
...
```

If you want only time or only date use one of those:
`CURRENT_TIME()` and `CURRENT_DATE()`

[Documentation can be found here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#functions-operators-aggregates).

Comment: Documentation link reports not found, please update.

Comment: This CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() thing has never has worked for me.  Could you provide an example of how that is used?  I don't wan't to use the web server's time, rather the database.  I always end up writing raw SQL (still binding params) and forgoing the query builder.

Comment: Also notice `'now'` is default param for `DateTime`, so `new \DateTime()` is enough.

Answer (score 9):

Using query builder it would look like this:

```
$qb
    ->select('B')
    ->from('RandomBundle:Banana', 'B')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->gt('B.expiresAt', ':now')
    )
    ->setParameter('now', '\'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()\'');
```

Note: extra quotes on parameter set is **required** to get `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` function working.

Or simply

```
$qb
    ->select('B')
    ->from('RandomBundle:Banana', 'B')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->gt('B.expiresAt', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()')
    );
```

Comment: In the second example, you can use the shorter `B.expiresAt > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` comparison directly inside the `where` call instead of using a query builder expression

Comment: I assume it was desired to use database's time, not some frontend web server's. Alternate options are to use a [resultset mapper/native query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html), or to extend Doctrine and write your own Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions.